# java.io.FileNotFoundException:(Access is denied) at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) Remote Tomcat Server read excel client machine

Tags: java, excel, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream, access-denied

I am working on a Web application that reads the excel file from the specified path and imports the data in the excel file to the oracle database. This functionality is absolutely working when I run it on my local tomcat machine but when I deploy it on the remote tomcat server It throws the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Z:\02_Information_DataBase\ImportingTool\eMan.xls (The     system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at modules.report.dao.POIExcelReaderDao.displayFromExcel(POIExcelReaderDao.java:156)
at modules.report.service.POIExcelReaderService.displayFromExcel(POIExcelReaderService.java:91)
at modules.report.controller.ReportController.service(ReportController.java:118)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
at modules.index.controller.IndexController.service(IndexController.java:87)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source
```

The remote tomcat server has enough permissions to the specified file path but even then it says that the access is denied.

I went through a lot of surfing on internet but in vain....none of the solutions helped me out. Could anyone share a piece of information regarding the issue .....???

Comment: Is Z a mapped drive?  Does the account running the server have access to that drive?

Comment: could you go at path `Z:\02_Information_DataBase\ImportingTool\ ` & check whether `eMan.xls` is present or not?? If NOT, create the file first at the start of the code..

Comment: Ya well the account where the server is running has enough permissions with the network drive that is mapped....and the file eMan.xls is existing in the specified location.........

Answer (score 0):

Z sounds like a mapped drive.

Mapped drives are not available for serverprocesses, that are startet as a service, even if they are running as a user.

[Use the full qualified UNC-path instead.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180362/en-us)

***update:**
It is possible to map the drive by the process itself and use it, but you should not do this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply....Well I have tried even with UNC path and no improvement in the result. Could you please give me any other idea which could drag me to a better position..??